# C++ why bitvec[0].flip() works

Tags: c++

Based on C++ Primer 4th edition (i.e. pp 105),

```
bitset<32> bitvec;

bitvec[0].flip(); // reverses the first bit.
```

My question is why the second line works? Based on

```
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/bitset/operator[]/

     bool operator[] ( size_t pos ) const;
reference operator[] ( size_t pos );
```

How can bitset::flit can be used on bool or reference?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"reference" returned by operator[] is not a C++ reference, it is a special proxy class that has flip() method.

Pseudo code:

```
class bitset
{
   class reference
   {
   public:
      reference& flip()
      {
         bitset_.flip(pos_);
         return *this;
      }

      reference(bitset& obj)
      : bitset_(obj), pos_(pos)
      {
      }

   bitset& bitset_;
   size_t pos_;
   };

   reference operator[](size_t pos)
   {
      return reference(*this, pos);
   }
}
```

See source code of your STL implementation for details.

Answer (score 2):

It returns an instance of `bitset<32>::reference`, which has a `flip` method.  More explicitly:

```
bitset<32> bs;
bitset<32>::reference first = bs[0];
first.flip();
```

Comment: May you give me a little detail how bitset<32>::reference works or you can give me some links where I can get more info -- thank you

Comment: You may want to look at SGI's [docs](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/bitset.html).  They note that it's a "proxy class that acts as a reference to a single bit."